# Jackson ObjectMapper readValue expected behavior when class properties change

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson2

I have a requirement to change properties of a class which is being serialized/deserialized by ObjectMapper.

This is my class.

```
// Old version
Class A {
    String id;
    String name;
}

// New version
Class A {
    String id;
    String firstName;
    String secondName;
}
```

I serialize the object `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()`, send it to a queue to process it later, and when received, deserialize it via `ObjectMapper.readValue()`.
What is the expected behavior of `readValue()` if the old version of Class A is serialized, but when deserializing - Class A has been updated to the new version.

Will `firstName` and `secondName` be null? Or `readValue()` throw an exception?

And what is the solution here to make the changes smoothly.

Comment: So what you want to do is migrating your data from an old version of A to a new version of A? So you dump your data using the old A and then read it again after you changed your class A to the new version? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @paradoxon  I want to essentially update Class A without any side effects to the application. Before deploying the change I will have multiple serialized objects in my Queue, after deployment when these messages are read and objects deserialized, how do I make sure they work as expected

Comment: When deserializing does the json string include firstName and secondName or you are expecting objectmapper to spring name into firstName and secondName?

Comment: No it will post null values for firstName and secondName. I want to design a solution were I can make the transition without affecting my application negatively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the first part as to what is the expected behavior if older object is deserialized, `objectMapper.readValue()` will deserialize with `firstName` and `secondName` being `null` while `name` being whatever was set. (I was expecting an exception which is not the case).

On how to make the transition:

I will not delete `name`. I will keep it along with `firstName` and `secondName`.

```
// Intermediate version
Class A {
    String id;
    String name;
    String firstName;
    String secondName;
}
```

`name` will be a dummy holder, and not used when serializing.

```
public void write(int id, String firstName, String secondName) {
    A a = new A();
    a.setId(id);
    a.setFirstName(firstName);
    a.setSecondName(secondName);
    bufferedWriter.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a));
}
```

Based on null check I will know whether the object belongs to older version or newer version.

```
public void read(String message) {
    A a = objectMapper.readValue(message);

    if(a.getName() != null) {
        // This object is older version of class A
        System.out.println("Name: " + a.getName());
        metric.emit("OldObjectA", 1);
    } else {
        // This object is newer version of class A
        System.out.println("Name: " + a.getFirstName() + " " + a.getSecondName())
    }
}
```

Once I'm sure I am not reading objects of older version, I will make the complete transition by removing `name`.

```
// Newer version
Class A {
    String id;
    String firstName;
    String secondName;
}
```